# Vox Populi Badge not given

Tags: support, badges, voting

I was fairly intensely running through a bunch of older posts this morning and used up all 40 of my votes.  When I try to upvote a question, I see:

[image: vote limit error message]

Totally normal.  What isn't normal is that the Vox Populi Progress remains at 38/40, and has done for the past hour or so.  Usually, it takes a few minutes, but this seems a bit long.

[image: vox populi badge counter at 38 of 40]

Is this a bug, or do is it taking a bit longer to come?

Comment: Did you *actually* vote on 40 posts? See [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes) - you only get 30 answer votes (plus 10 question votes)

Comment: @Aurora, good point, but I am unable to vote on questions and answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **aren't guaranteed 40 votes per day**, which may seem confusing (and I think it *is*!), so here are the rules, summarised from [*What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes) on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [You **always** get 30 votes, which you can use for whatever you like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90209/336144)
- After that, your vote cap is dictated by the formula in the first link:

  > min( 30 + ⌊1.2×*Q*<sub>25</sub>⌋, 40 )

  Where `⌊⌋` means "round down" and Q<sub>25</sub> is the number of question votes in your first 25 votes.
- In effect, the above means that you must have **voted on questions at least 9 times within your first 25 votes** to get the maximum of 10 'bonus votes'
- The other catch is that **as soon as you see the *'_ votes remaining'* warning, that's it** - you will not be able to get any more votes for today no matter what you do.

I suspect you only voted on 8 questions in your first 25 votes (Q<sub>25</sub> = 8 / 1.2), giving you only 8 bonus votes.